# How to change an option in a select list js

Tags: javascript, events, select, button

I have an event on change for a select list and I have to ask the user with a prompt window after he selects an option, what is the other option he wants to select, and then introduces the value in the prompt window, the selected option changes with the new one.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Examen modulo1</title>
    <script>

        function cambiaSelect() {
            var provincias = document.getElementById("provincias");
            var posicion = provincias.selectedIndex;
            var select = provincias.options[posicion].value;
            var pantalla;

            // when prompt value is 0
            if (provincias.options[posicion].value == 0) {
                alert("No has seleccionado ninguna provincia");
            } else {
                // when index is selected
                if (provincias.options[posicion].selected == true) {
                    pantalla = prompt("Has seleccionado la provincia: " + provincias.options[posicion].text + "\n Introduce otra provincia aqui:");
                }
                // when prompt do not receive a value
                if (pantalla == "") {
                    alert("El valor que has introducido no existe!\Intentalo de nuevo!");
                }
                //prompt equals the selected value
                if (select == pantalla && provincias.options[posicion].selected == true) {
                    alert("Esa provincia ya esta seleccionada");
                }
            }
        }//cambia
    </script>
</head>

<body>
4.Formulario de tipo select. Selecciona provincias:<br>

<form method="GET">

    <br>
    <select id="provincias">
        <option value="0">0.Selecciona...</option>
        <option value="1">1.Albacete</option>
        <option value="2">2.Murcia</option>
        <option value="3">3.Madrid</option>
    </select><br>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Cambiar" onclick="cambiaSelect()"><br>
    <br>
    <br>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: my point is: when the user introduces in prompt the new value of the wanted  option , get the value and select it automatically in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run the code below by clicking "Run code snippet". If the user enters 3, selected option will change to "3.Madrid". The Spanish was confusing me, so I switched it to English, but the programming logic is the same.

```html
<form method="GET">
  <br>
  <select id="provincias">
    <option value="0">0.Selecciona...</option>
    <option value="1">1.Albacete</option>
    <option value="2">2.Murcia</option>
    <option value="3">3.Madrid</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="Cambiar" onclick="cambiaSelect()">

</form>

<script>
  function cambiaSelect() {
    var provinces = document.getElementById("provincias");
    var position = provinces.selectedIndex;
    var select = provinces.options[position].value;
    var pantalla;

    if (provinces.options[position].value == 0) {
      alert("You have not selected any province");
    } else {
      if (provinces.options[position].selected == true) {
        pantalla = prompt("You have selected the province: " + provinces.options[position].text + "\n Choose another province here");
        while (true) {
          if (pantalla) { // this ensures that if the user clicks cancel on the prompt, we don't do any more logic
            if (pantalla === "") {
              alert("The value you entered does not exist. Try again!");
            } else if (select === pantalla) {
              alert("That province is already selected");
            } else if (pantalla >= 1 && pantalla <= 3) {
              document.getElementById('provincias').selectedIndex = pantalla;
              break;
            }
            pantalla = prompt("Choose another province here");
          } else { // if the cancel button on prompt was pressed, get out of loop
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

The only problem is if the user enters a number between 1 and 3 which is not an integer, say 2.5. 2.5 is not a proper index, right? So if you wanted to deal with that case you can add this modification:

`else if (Number.isInteger(Number(pantalla)) && pantalla >= 1 && pantalla <= 3)`. Let me know if you have more questions.